# Wiki & Tutorial Updates

Tags: ros, wiki, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I couldn't find any proper procedure for updating the ROS wiki and tutorial pages, if there is one.  Specifically I'm looking at fleshing out the openSUSE installation section and some pages on using custom messages.

Are there any ROS-specific update procedure description pages?  I assume updating the openSUSE pages will be less of an issue than updating the widely used tutorials.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38317/wiki-&-tutorial-updates/) by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on ROS Answers with karma: 506 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS wiki runs on community contributions. Thank you for offering to help. You are welcome to edit any page you feel you can improve.

These style guides may help:

- [Wiki Style Guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/StyleGuide)
- [Writing Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/WritingTutorials)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-07-09**:
@joq Thanks.  I didn't see these links before, but now I see where they are linked from on the ROS wiki.